# cut background img by the left on resize

Tags: css, image

I can't figure out how to make it so that when a window can't display the whole image, it cuts the image on the left.

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/H3Vqc/) always cuts the right side using:

```
img {
      position:fixed;
}​
```

Comment: maybe your showing your code will help.

Comment: I hate it when my windows cut things too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `right:0;` if you want to cut the left side on resize. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Vqc/1/ and test.

**Further:**

- If you want to resize the image when you resize the **browser** then use `width: 100%`.
- If you want to hide the right side set `position: absolute;` and `left:0;`

Answer (score 1):

or u can simply apply dir="rtl" on the div the image is on this results on what you want

```
 <div dir="rtl"><img src="yourImg.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly assuming if you are using css background you can use the [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property to position your image, and use width and height to get it to the right size

Comment: yes, but when I sesize the window and and the img has reached the min-width it always cuts the right side of the image, I need it to cut the left side

Comment: Good for you - excellent assumption considering no code was given :)

Comment: fiddle on top, thought it was obvious, sorry

Comment: @Daniil sorry but w3schools is providing the exact example i want to show.

Comment: @Ibu, w3schools is a bad resource to refer as long as it has many mistakes even if this article doen't have them.

Comment: @Daniil there is no mistake on the link i provided at least not that i see. if you see a mistake please show me and i will be glad to change the link.

Comment: @Ibu, this article doesn't have mistakes, but w3schools itself does. Checkout http://w3fools.com/ to see. As long as it has many mistakes it is not a good site to refer. Why? Because users can think this site is a good source of information when it isn't.

Answer (score -2):

You likely want to set `max-width: 100%` to the `<img>`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Vqc/4/